# else if clause not executing in for loop python

Tags: python

```
num_input = open('final_activity_io_text.txt')
new_var = num_input.read()
num_list = (int(i) for i in new_var)

catch = (i for i in num_list if i > 3)

if (i for i in num_list if i > 3):
    print(*catch, sep='\n')
elif (i for i in num_list if i <= 3):
    print('None!')
```

hi, I've tested my program with inputs such as 45, 123456, and 798, and it works but with inputs that are lesser than 4, the else-if doesn't work. I've tried changing to to just "else:", and still doesn't work.

Comment: You probably want to rewrite that entirely. Make a loop, put if/elif in it, problem solved. Now it looks like you tried to put several things in one and the if/elif doesn't work this way with conditions inside. Now the if is run only once, not for each value separately.

Comment: This is barely readable. Don't use if and a for loop with if inside parenthesis.

Comment: Could you explain what you expect your program to do and what it does now ?

Comment: Yes. It's supposed to accept a single line containing a single integer for input, and the output must be a new line that prints each digit greater than 3 and a single line that contains the word "none" if there are no numbers greater than 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use generator expressions as the condition of if-statements. Generators are lazily evaluated & are inherently "truth-y".

Check this example:

```
nums = list(range(100))


gen_full = (i for i in nums if i < 3)
gen_empty = (i for i in nums if i > 100)

print(bool(gen_full))
print(bool(gen_empty))
```

Which prints:

```
True
True
```

even though the second generator would be empty.

What you should be doing is using the `any` function.

```
print(any(i > 100 for i in nums))
```

Which prints:

```
False
```

So you can change your code to:

```
if any(i for i in num_list if i > 3):
    print(*catch, sep='\n')
elif any(i for i in num_list if i <= 3):
    print('None!')
```